# помогите разобраться в работе данного кода.(Взаимная блокировка)

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте,Я правильно понимаю,что сначала запускается первая нить,а так как код читается последовательно,сначала запуститься первая нить,затем сработает ошибка,а после запуститься вторая нить? тогда в какой момент произойдет блокировка(deadlock)?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        t1.start();
        t1.interrupt()
        t2.start();
    }
    public static class T1 extends Thread {@
        Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                t2.join();
                System.out.println("T1 finished");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("T1 was interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
    public static class T2 extends Thread {@
        Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                t1.join();
                System.out.println("T2 finished");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("T2 was interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код, в том виде, в котором вы его привели, не содержит deadlock'а. (Я предполагаю, что переменные `t1` и `t2` являются объектами типов `T1` и `T2` соответственно.)

Действительно, рассмотрим поток `t1`. Он может ожидать только в `t2.join();`. Если он остановится там ожидать, то рано или поздно основной поток выполнит (или выполнил раньше) `t1.interrupt()`, что приведёт к выходу из ожидания, отработке исключения и завершению этого потока.

Теперь, поток `t2`. Он может ждать лишь в `t1.join();`, на как мы видим, `t1` завершается, так что и вызов `join()` завершится.

Если у вас есть deadlock, он где-то в другом месте.